# How to replace html tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change div and span tags to tr td using java script.
But java script replace function only replace the first occurrence and leaves rest as it was.

```
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #DDDDDD; padding:10px 0px; height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
    <span style="width:420px; display:block; float:left; border-bottom:1px thin #333333;background:#F2F2F2">
      Custom Stirrups : Category - Adult ,Size-One size fits most 
    </span> 
    <span style="width:220px; display:block; float:left; border-bottom:1px thin #333333;background:#F2F2F2">
      NO
    </span>
    <span style="width:140px; display:block; float:left; border-bottom:1px thin #333333;background:#F2F2F2">
      1
    </span><br />
  </div>
  <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #DDDDDD; padding:10px 0px; height:100%; overflow:hidden;"> 
    <span style="width:420px; display:block; float:left; border-bottom:1px thin #333333;background:#F2F2F2">
      Flat Visor Fitted : Fitted Sizes - 7 1/8 
    </span> 
    <span style="width:220px; display:block; float:left; border-bottom:1px thin #333333;background:#F2F2F2">
      NO 
    </span> 
    <span style="width:140px; display:block; float:left; border-bottom:1px thin #333333;background:#F2F2F2">
      1
    </span>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want something similar to this

```
<table width="100%">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="471" style="background:#F2F2F2">Cap : Fitted Sizes - 6 5/8 </td>
            <td width="240" style="background:#F2F2F2">YES</td>
            <td width="145" style="background:#F2F2F2">1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="471" style="background:#F2F2F2">Grey Dri-fit Undershirt : Size - XXL </td>
            <td width="240" style="background:#F2F2F2">YES</td>
            <td width="145" style="background:#F2F2F2">1</td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

this is my script which i was trying...please let me know where i m wrong

```
var data = $('#dvData').html();
  data = data.replace('/<div style="width:100%">/g', '<table width="100%"><tbody><tr>');
  data = data.replace('/</div>/g', '</tbody></table></tr>');
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You have an issue with quotation marks, I guess, please see below.

Comment: Probably another approach would be to redefine the css styles :)

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp
It's for global replacement:

```
var str="Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car";
var n=str.replace(/blue/g,"red");
```

Other examples are provided there as well.

Comment: i have tried the same but its not working for some reason..don't know why

Comment: Instead of
     data = data.replace('/</div>/g', '</tbody></table></tr>');
try
     data = data.replace(/</div>/g, '</tbody></table></tr>');

The first parameter without quotation marks, because it's a regular expression, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I see you tagged also jquery, so assume you also accept jquery?

You could use [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) for this.

```
$('span, div, tr , td').replaceWith('Replaced!');
```

Answer (score 0):

well ,
 when dom is parsed it unchangable/immutable

you can try this:

```
$('div').contents().unwrap().wrap('<tr/>');
```

look at the tr tag there...

of if it dosent works try this

```
$(this).replaceWith($('<tr>' + this.innerHTML + '</tr>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this..I know its not the best way to do it...

```
var data = $('#dvData').html();
  data = data.toString();
    data = data.replace('<div style="width:100%">', '<table width="100%">');
data = data.replace('span', 'td');
```

Answer (score 0):

So try using .replaceAll(). if it doesn't help, use a loop.